# UISearchBar subview strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, subview

I have added the `UISearchDisplayController` via Interface Builder, and then I add the `UISearchBar` to my `navigationBar` like this

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

It works and looks fine. What I then want to do is add a subview to the `searchBar` (to act as a placeholder image). I do it by

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar addSubview:self.imageView];
```

The problem is, the `imageView` is not visible. I `NSLog` its `superview` and I get a confirmation that it's the `searchBar`. I can also see that the `searchBar` has 1 `subview`, but when I log the `subview`, it tells me that it's... drum-rolls... the `searchBar` itself.

How can this be?

**EDIT**

Interestingly, if I add the `searchBar` to `navigationBar` as a subview and the add my `imageView`, it's visible. The problem is only when the `searchBar` is being added to `navigationBar` by `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES`.

Comment: show ur code or screenshot.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish here. Do you want to add an image on top of the searchBar or something like this: Where you want to change the search icon? ![Search Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RNcxg.png)

Comment: Yes, I want to add an imageView on top of / over the searchBar

Comment: I have already provided the code that I believe is relevant to this question. What additionally would you like to see?

Comment: Then add it as a subview to the view.

So it would be like this: [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];

Comment: did u adjust ur imageView frame Size.

Comment: `UINavigationBar` sits above `self.view`, so this would result in my `imageView` being behind the `navBar`

Comment: Yes, I can add it to any other view and it's visible

Comment: increase width and height of ur imageview to see if it is visible.i too was not able to view it but increasing width and height was able to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it - I hope this helps someone. The strange thing about adding a `searchBar` to `navigationBar` like this

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

is that the 'didLayoutSubviews' is called twice in the `viewController`, i.e. the `searchDisplayController` adds the `searchBar` to the `navigationBar` with a delay that I was not able to capture through existing delegate methods.

What I ended up doing instead is setting the `zIndex` of my `imageView` to maximum

```
self.imageView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
```

so even if the `searchDisplayController` adds the `searchBar` to the `navigationBar` with a delay, the `imageView` still stays on top.